# scroll bar not working in the google chrome when running Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css, google-chrome, scroll

I have three `devise_form`

1. `devise_for :authorize`
2. `devise_for :employe`
3. `devise_for :hr`

`when i signed_in` as a `authorize` or  `hr`

**The scrolldown in google crome works perfectly in every page**

`but as soon as i signed_in as a`**employee** `working of scrolldown doesnt works on any on any page`

`here are the images with scrolldown and without scrolldown`

[image: This image is with scrolldown]

`Now without scrolldown`
[image: WITHOUT SCROLLDOWN]

`I HAVE ALSO TRIED`

```
body {
overflow : scroll ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the issue in my case was , I had the version of code that did not have devise incorporated in it. I worked on it and did a fresh addition of devise into it. Strange as it may sound, that fixed the issue.

Seems to be some tiny mistake made in the configuration of devise.

If you have stumbled upon any other solution, please share it in this thread. Will turn out to be useful for someone.